# Firestore error : Stream closed with status : PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: firebase, kotlin

I am trying to use firestore to certain data,but i can't see any data in firestore console
error:

```
(c4326c7) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Cloud Firestore API has not been used in project 508621789005 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firestore.googleapis.com/overview?project=508621789005 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., cause=null}.
```

Although i allowed read,write in rules to true.

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    // Create a new user with a first and last name
            val user: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            user["first"] = "Ada"
            user["last"] = "Lovelace"
            user["born"] = 1815

    // Add a new document with a generated ID
            db.collection("users")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                    Log.d(
                        TAG,
                        "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.id
                    )
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e) }
```

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please share your database rules as well

Comment: I added rules to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a new project.Becuase it seems that there was a problem in project id.

Comment: Yes the problem could happen due to different project id but it can be solved by just making a clean project call. I solved it with ur reference. Tnx

Comment: Ohh..thank god. I resolved my issue because of you. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you. Creating new Project solved this issue

Comment: Is there a way to check if there is an id mismatch? I might be having the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

Replace your rules with this and try:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{multiSegment=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: @MohamedAmin Just edited my answer. try it. if it works, most probably your rules hierarchy doesn't match your rules hierarchy. Please add an image of your database structure so I can change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This error can also occur if you haven't actually created the DB in your Firebase console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I solved it by removing the file:

```
app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml
```

This file contained references to old google APIs and for some reason it wasn't being overwritten in the project `build`.  When I manually removed the `build` process it was created again with the correct references.

> If you use **Android Studio** just click on the top menu on `Build` and
> then on `Clean Project` and you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**Clearing the project cache** solved the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

**Worked For Me:**

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

try to enable the function from firebase. for my part, I forgot to enable cloud firestore when migrate to a new account. Try that !

Answer (score 0):

Will opening the project for edit in android studio and letting it sync and making its indexing then giving it the permission to update the Gradle version did solve the problem for me,
that happened because I added a new google-service.json file without doing that step.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and Synchronise with Gradle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

replacing `google-services.json` with the new one I got from firebase solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue for five hours, finally solved it.

change Cloud Firestore, rules
allow read, write: if false  to this allow read, write;

Answer (score 0):

the project id is incorrect. the project id must be in this format in your project settings: projectname:xxxxx

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: const FirebaseOptions(
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "nameproject-xxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  androidClientId:
      'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
),
```